# FCGI & PHP 5.4.x not loading .user.ini

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using a `.user.ini` file by placing it into my docroot of an application.  When I check the phpinfo.php I am not seeing anything amiss.  Unfortunately I am also not seeing values such as `post_max_size=16M` set either and only the global `php.ini` settings are active.

How would I track this issue down as it is eluding me presently as to why the `.user.ini` is apparently not being recognized?

Just to note, I have set the `user_ini.cache_ttl` to 10 seconds and verified that `user_ini.filename` is set to `.user.ini.`.  Further I've, just for good measure, restarted the web server to make sure all php procs are defunct and die and that it spins up new php procs.

A quick sample `.user.ini` I'm trying to use for testing is:

```
log_errors=1
error_log="/home/username/php-errors.log"
post_max_size=16M
date.timezone="America/New_York"
```

Apparently there are [some issues in certain scenarios](http://www.ait-pro.com/aitpro-blog/4349/misc-projects/wordpress-tips-tricks-fixes/php5-3-x-php5-4-x-user-ini-file-does-not-work-known-php5-3-x-user-ini-fastcgi-wordpress-zend-issue/) and it has been recommended, that, when you have control over the situation, one should opt for suphp instead of FCGI.  I fear though that I would be losing a number of advantages with too few gains by following this recommendation.  Any thoughts / experiences on this area would likewise be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case there was a silly error that I caught after taking a look at the file permissions again.  It appears that I had two terminals open; one logged in as the proper user and the other as an admin user.  I had created the file as an admin user inadvertantly and simply needed to `chown` it over to the proper `username:groupname`.  After that, the problem went away.